# Why do questions get migrated to other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, migration

For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315893/firebug-1-6-bug-closed

It's really obnoxious, in my opinion.

Comment: That's more of a question for meta, if that. All I can say is... "welcome to the Internet". Everything gets stolen and reposted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the question you are linking to has been migrated to superuser.com because it is not programming-related. Yours should be on meta.stackoverflow.com and might also be migrated there.

Comment: Ah, I see. You mean "why do questions get migrated to other stack exchange sites"? Because those sites are much better suited for an answer. You don't go to a gardening website to ask questions about how to fix your car. Likewise, you don't ask about configuring a web server on a programming website.

Comment: And "stealing" content from SO is allowed by the license(CC-BY-SA) provided you credit the original author and license the derivative product as CC-BY-SA too.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71363/why-do-i-have-to-have-logins-on-a-zillion-other-overflow-sites-one-should-be-eno

Answer (score 1):

Because they're not programming questions (at least, the example you give is not one).

See the [very first question in the faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq): what kind of questions can I ask here?

Comment: in the specific case, "tools that programmers commonly user" is a valid question on SO
Firebug is defiantly falls under that

Comment: @user152476: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say. *Defiantly* means that Firebug doesn't want to fall under that, it is boldly resisting. So everything's in order here? Or did you actually mean *definitely*? Spelling matters if you don't want to be misunderstood.

Comment: i am saying that firebug "definitely" falls under a developer tool, so questions about firebug are on topic for stack overflow

Comment: User, if that was the basis, then we do our development on a computer, so there's no need for superuser at all.  We run apps on servers; no need for serverfault.  It's not because it *couldn't* go on stackoverflow, but because it is *much better suited* elsewhere.