# Why do I have to have logins on a zillion other overflow sites. One should be enough?

Tags: discussion, login

I wanted to answer a question about Firebug:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315893/firebug-1-6-bug-closed
but it was moved to another site.

When I asked why the question was moved, my question what also moved to yet another site!

I don't want to login in to three different sites. The entire reason that stackoverflow works is that it is one site. Now that the questions are being spread out, I for one will quit coming back.

Please stop moving questions that posters put here!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71360/why-do-questions-on-stack-overflow-get-stolen-and-posted-on-other-se-sites

Comment: This has happened before, first a question about a question being migrated, then followed up with confusion over multiple sites. Last time had much less hyperbole, however. I wonder if I can find it again...

Comment: Do these 'I quit coming back' threats ever have any real teeth?  Do we care?  Losing some that just don't want to make any kind of effort to get an answer sounds like a good outcome to me.

Comment: @Hans Passant: This is actually someone who wanted to *answer*, not *get* an answer.

Comment: @Michael - ah yes, subtle difference, not.  I was delighted to find out I had more than the standard 100 rep at su.com from moved questions that I posted an answer to and got upvotes after the move.  That glass is half-full.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you **don't** have to login to *any* stack exchange site in order to ask questions or view them and the answers.

I was moved because it was **not a programming question**.

This is also **not a programming question** and will be moved to meta.

StackOverflow is a programming question and answer site, as is clearly stated in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Other stack exchange sites are for other things.

Comment: This goes against what Jeff said in the blog about members who add value. As far as I know this is the head of Firebug development, after Joe stepped down. A tool which is invaluable to a high percentage of people on this site. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/

Comment: @Wes: I'm pretty sure Adriano Gondim (the person who posted the Firebug question) is *not* the head of firebug development.

Comment: @balpha but the preson asking this question is.

Comment: @Wes: If you're suggesting that "Why do I have to have logins on a zillion other overflow sites. One should be enough!??" should have stayed on Stack Overflow because it's been asked by a Firebug developer, you're misunderstanding the blog post. If you're suggesting that "Firebug 1.6 bug" should have stayed on Stack Overflow, that has nothing to do with johnjbarton.